# My HTML email is displaying Serif instead of Sans-serif in Yahoo Mail

Tags: html-email, yahoo-mail

I have a newsletter almost ready to send in HTML format, and I've succeeded in making it look almost identical across all the major email clients and web mail services (Outlook, Gmail, Yahoo Mail, Hotmail, AOL, etc. -- yeah, not an easy task at all).

There is one annoying exception, though: Yahoo Mail changes my **Sans-serif** font to **Serif**.

I've coded my HTML email by the book (Ref: [Guide to CSS support in email](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/)), and I've tried some suggested solutions, but none seem to work.

***Edit:*** Here's an excerpt of my HTML code:

```
<table width="100%" style="font-family:Arial; font-size:13px; border-collapse:collapse">
  <tr>
    <td style="padding:5px"><font face="Arial">...some text...</font></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I have used both inline CSS and the `<font>` tag to declare my font, as suggested at some site, but nothing.

As for the markup generated by Yahoo, all I can see is a lot of JavaScript since this issue, curiously enough, only applies to the modern Yahoo Mail interface.

Is there anyone here who has come across this issue and has a proven solution?

Cheers,

Mark

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I stop Yahoo displaying serif fonts in HTML emails when I've specified sans-serif?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6862388/how-do-i-stop-yahoo-displaying-serif-fonts-in-html-emails-when-ive-specified-sa)

Answer (score 0):

Put `font-family: arial, sans-serif;` as an inline style inside the `td`.

E.g., `<td style="font-family: arial, sans-serif;">`